# Нужно чтобы значение атрибута value одного из тегов input было >2, а если оно меньше, то при наведении мыши на кнопку button становилось =2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, теги, атрибуты

Ниже часть кода написал. Не работает. В чём здесь может быть ошибка?

### html

```
<input id="c" value="1" type="number" />
<button> Посчитать </button>
```

### js

```
function isright(c) {
    if (c.value < 2)
        c.value = 2;
}
jQuery('button').on('mouseover', isright('#c'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `isright` вызывается не в момент наведения мыши, а в момент установки обработчика. Правильный код:

```
function isright() {
    let element = $('#c');
    if (+element.val() < 2) {
        element.val(2);
    }
}
$('button').on('mouseover', isright);
```

Comment: `if (+$(c).val() < 2) { $(c).val(2); }`

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь работает

Comment: @Евгений галочка слева - щёлк :)